# Proper usage of viewset queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

According to [Django REST framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/), the following two code snippets should behave identically.

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for listing or retrieving users.
    """
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        user = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset for viewing and editing user instances.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

But the way I interpret it, in the first case the query `User.objects.all()` is run with every api call, which in the second case, the query is run only once when the web server is started, since it's  class variable. Am I wrong ? At least in my tests, trying to mock User.objects.all will fail, since the UserViewSet.queryset will already be an empty Queryset object by that time.

Someone please explain me why shouldn't the queryset class argument be avoided like pest and get_queryset be used instead ?
Edit: replacing queryset with get_queryset makes self.queryset undefined in the retrieve method, so I need to use self.get_queryset() within the method as well...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. you are wrong, django queries are lazy so in both case the query will run at response time

from django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy):

> QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long, and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is evaluated

2. `ModelViewSet` provides other actions like `delete` and `update` you may need to add some limitations on them for user model (like checking permissions or maybe you don't like to let users simply delete their profiles)
3. `self.queryset` is used for router and basename and stuff, you can ignore it and set basename in your router manually. it's not forced but I think it make my code more readable

note that usually `def get_queryset` is used when you want to do some actions on default queryset for example limit `self.queryset` based on current user. so if `get_queryset` is going to return `.objects.all()` or `.objects.filter(active=True)` I suggest using `self.queryset` to have a cleaner code

note2: if you decide to define `get_queryset` I suggest to also define `self.queryset` (if possible)

note3: always use `self.get_queryset` in your view method, even you didn't defined this method, you may need need to create that method later and if your view method are using `self.queryset` it may cause some issues in your code

Comment: Indeed, I had forgotten about the lazy part, thanks. Wondering why I cannot unit test UserViewSet.queryset with a mock on User.objects.all.

Comment: I think the problem with mock can be in another question, but I have no idea that why are you trying to change default query you may need to fill table with valid data using `factoryboy` or `fixtures` on run tests on them instead of mocking query

Comment: The point is to write "unit" tests, not bloated tests requiring db transactions. Thanks for the suggestion, will open another question if I can't figure this on my own

Comment: Looks like I can test the queryset.model and queryset.query fields, so that will do for now. thanks again for the support!

Comment: happy to able to help

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Aliva's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51220687/4111227) and quoting from DRF viewset code, under `get_queryset()` method definition it states:

> This method should always be used rather than accessing `self.queryset`
> directly, as `self.queryset` gets evaluated only once, and those results
> are cached for all subsequent requests. You may want to override this if you need to provide different
> querysets depending on the incoming request.